# Missing 1 of 6 bags to a set, how can I identify what parts are missing

Tags: part-identification

I bought a used set and it has 5/6 bags.  How can I identify what parts are in bag 1 so I can order them?   Set is 7964

Answer (score 4):

[Lego's own building instructions](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions/7964) will show you which bag you open when, so if you are willing to look at each step before bag 2 is used, they must have come from bag 1 (unfortunately, this includes minifigures).

[image: 7964]

Comment: This is fairly easy to do if you add all the pieces to a wishlist in Bricklink (go to the page for the set and then click on the Part Out link under My Wanted List. You can now go through the building steps from the manual and mark each piece needed in the wanted list. When done with the first bag you have a list of all the pieces you need, and you can order them straight away from Bricklink using the list and the Buy All option.)

Comment: This sounds like the easiest way to get this done at this point, but hopefully somebody will compile a database of these someday.  This is a good bricklink project for TLG to fund now that they've taken over. :)

Comment: I, for one, would prefer they spend their money elsewhere, instead of on maintaining a database that almost nobody ever uses. If they already **have** the data (and surely they must, to fill the bags) in such a way they could easily export to BrickLink (much less likely), then sure, why not.

Comment: Perhaps they would rather not share that data as not to help the clone brick manufacturers

Comment: True. They already publish it in the instructions, but there's a difference between making information available and making it **easy**. Anyone who wants to can measure a 2x4 brick, but that doesn't mean Lego needs to go out of their way to publish the size.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any LEGO related online catalogs keeping track of individual bag contents. So there is no convenient way of knowing what's missing.

One way is to do as mentioned by RSchulz, but I find it tedious to identify each piece and make a note of them.

If you are willing to open the rest of the bags you could check against existing set inventories on [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=7964-1) or [Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/sets/7964-1/republic-frigate/#parts). Such way you don't need to identify the name (the most tedious, probably), part number and color. Only thing is needed is to note the quantity you already have.

Comment: peeron.com used to have a bag field, but that hasn't been maintained for a long time.